# How do I specific creation of a link without params in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

In my view, I want to use link_to_unless_current create a link to "/payforms" when I'm on page.  However, when I pass parameters, such as, "/payforms?submitted=true", for example, the function still thinks I'm on "current" and the link is not created.  Is there a way for me to check if there are no parameters?

```
<%= link_to_unless_current "All", payforms_path %>
```

Maybe something like this?

```
<%= link_to_unless_current "All", payforms_path(:params => nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, it shouldn't be the case.

You can check if page is the same by

```
<%= current_page?(payforms_path) %>
```

or construct target url by

```
<%= CGI.unescapeHTML(url_for(payforms_path)) %>
```

Probably last expression returns '/payforms/submitted' too.

**on updated question**
You can declare your own validation function, in application_helper.rb for example, and then pass it to `link_to_unless` call.

```
<%= link_to_unless same_page?(payforms_path), "All", payforms_path %>
```

Some hints on how to implement `same_page?` check, see `current_page?` in url_helper.rb. Basically, you just need to throw-away parameters check:

```
    # We ignore any extra parameters in the request_uri if the 
    # submitted url doesn't have any either.  This lets the function
    # work with things like ?order=asc 
    if url_string.index("?")
      request_uri = request.request_uri
    else
      request_uri = request.request_uri.split('?').first
    end
```

-->

```
    request_uri = request.request_uri
```

Comment: Actually, the question was incorrect - I'm looking for a way to see if params is empty.  Is there a function like this in rails?